# bash compgen -d -- '~' always produce empty output

Tags: bash, autocomplete

```
bash$ compgen -d -- '~'
```

Produces empty output.

```
bash$ compgen -d -- '~mi'
```

Also produces empty output.

```
bash$ compgen -d -- '~mice/'
~mice/.pulse
~mice/.mozilla
~mice/Pictures
```

Is OK.

```
bash$ compgen -d -- '~mice/Do'
~mice/Downloads
~mice/Documents
```

Also OK.

Is it a bug in compgen that it is produces empty output for '~' and '~mi'?
If it is a bug, will it break something when fixed?

Answer (score 4):

The first two, I suspect, need to be completed as tilde expansions before they can be completed as directory names.

```
bash$ compgen -u -- '~mi'
~mice
```

You cannot, however, specify both `-d` and `-u` in the same call to `compgen`.

Note the following:

```
bash$ compgen -d -- '~/'     # Like #1, but with trailing /: it works
bash$ compgen -d -- '~mice'  # Like #3, but w/o trailing /: it doesn't work
```

So incomplete tilde expansions will not be expanded to the proper directory by `-d`, and "complete" means including the terminating path separator character.

---

It *might* be worth filing a [bug report](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html), although I suspect it works as intended. At the very least, you might get a better explanation for the current behavior.